# What's the most efficient way to reload all rows in a tableview except the first cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata, indexpath

I have items in a `tableview` , and i want to reload or update the `tableview` data  , except the first row or the first indexpath of the tableview.

```
 let visibleIndex = self.tableView.visibleCells.compactMap {  
 tableView.indexPath(for: $0)  }
  self.tableView.reloadRows(at: visibleIndex, with: .automatic)
```

However this reloads all the visible cells , how do i reload all the visible cells except the first row

Comment: what is the reason about you do not want first cell of tableview reload ? Why do not you make is sectionHeaderView ? Or you can give those cell models a flag telling it not to update view when tableview tries to reload it. There could be so many different solutions for that :). If you do not want that cell update, then it should not be cell :) .

Comment: note the answer depends on whether all cells are visible or not ??? meaning they all fit in screen ?

Comment: @erkutbas The reason is that when i click on a cell at any position , the cell must move to the top , and then i can start editing the cell values manually, while the other cells are being updated automatically .

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes , all cells loaded by the tableview from the datasource whether they are visible or not , or whether they fit in screen or i have to scroll to make them visible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to get the visible cells. Use `indexPathsForVisibleRows` and remove the index path for section 0, row 0.

```
let allButFirst = (self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []).filter { $0.section != 0 || $0.row != 0 }
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: allButFirst, with: .automatic)
```

Comment: However is it possible for that ignored `Cell` data item be found at another indexPath. example a list of names  `["Food","Sleep","Code"]` populated into a tableview, now the first index which is **Food** has been moved to the top and prevented from being updated  , but still want to see the **Food** appear again at the last or not first indexPath

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the first visible cell is the 1 on the most top You can do

```
 self.tableView.reloadRows(at: Array(visibleIndex.dropFirst()), with: .automatic)
```

Or if not

```
let visibleIndex = self.tableView.visibleCells.compactMap {
    tableView.indexPath(for: $0)  }.filter { $0.row != 0 } 
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: visibleIndex, with: .automatic)
```

==

```
let visibleIndex:[IndexPath] = self.tableView.visibleCells.compactMap { item in
    let index = self.tableView.indexPath(for:item)!
    return index.row != 0 ? index : nil
}
```